# How to write this SQL (about date and time)?

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, case-when

spot_datetime

```
2019-04-10  17:36:00
2019-04-05  17:22:00
2019-04-03  18:52:00
2019-04-09  18:12:00
2019-04-05  18:14:00
2019-04-12  16:23:00
2019-04-09  18:43:00
2019-04-16  18:35:00
2019-04-11  16:53:00
2019-04-25  00:57:00
2019-04-09  00:25:00
2019-04-21  00:59:00
2019-04-24  01:04:00
2019-02-25  00:59:00
2019-04-09  02:41:00
2019-04-17  03:28:00
2019-02-24  02:55:00
2019-02-24  03:26:00
2019-02-25  02:47:00
2019-04-16  23:27:00
2019-04-23  21:01:00
```

...

A broadcast date starts at 6:00:00 AM ET and ends at 5:59:59 AM ET. So if a spot aired  on June 3rd at 7:00:00 AM ET, then that spot's broadcast date is June 3rd. But if a spot aired on June 3rd at 5:00:00 AM ET, then that spot's broadcast date is June 2nd. Please include a calculated field in your query that gives the broadcast date of each spot.

I tried to write sql with CASE WHEN function, CAST and DATE_FORMAT, DATE_ADD to compare spot_datetime to identify the broadcast date, but it doesn't work.

```
select spot_datetime,
case when date_format(spot_datetime, '%h:%i:%s') < cast(06:00:00 as time)
then ...
eles date_add(spot_datetime, interval 1 day) end as broadcast_date
from TABLE_A;
```

Show a new column of broadcast date of each spot.

Comment: Are you outsourcing your homework?

Comment: It also doesn't help that you misspelled "else"

Answer (score 2):

Why not just subtract six hours from the datetime, and then truncate the time portion e.g.

```
SELECT r.spot_datetime
     , DATE( r.spot_datetime + INTERVAL -6 HOUR ) AS bcast_date
  FROM ( SELECT '2019-06-03 05:00' AS spot_datetime
         UNION ALL SELECT '2019-06-03 06:00'
         UNION ALL SELECT '2019-06-03 07:00'
       ) r
```

returns

```
spot_datetime     bcast_date
----------------  ----------
2019-06-03 05:00  2019-06-02
2019-06-03 06:00  2019-06-03
2019-06-03 07:00  2019-06-03
```

(This assumes that there are no timezone conversions needed i.e. the broadcast date boundaries are marked in the same timezone as spot_datetime.)

---

We should have test cases for Daylight Saving Time change Sunday in the spring and fall:

```
spot_datetime     bcast_date
----------------  ----------

2019-03-10 05:00  2019-03-09
2019-03-10 05:30  2019-03-09
2019-03-10 06:00  2019-03-10

2019-11-03 05:00  2019-11-02
2019-11-03 05:30  2019-11-02
2019-11-03 06:00  2019-11-03
```

---

But if we are going to go with an approach with DATE_FORMAT, note that `'%h'` format is twelve hour clock (01..12) that's for both AM and PM, so we'd really need to add an AM/PM discriminator. Or we could use `'%H'` format model for 24 hour clock (00..23)

e.g.

```
DATE(spot_datetime) + INTERVAL IF(DATE_FORMAT(spot_datetime,'%H') < '06',-1,0) DAY
```